# how to properly install Json.net via nuget for windows phone 7.1 and Silverlight v.4,0

Tags: c#, silverlight, json.net, windows-phone-7.1

I need to use json.net for json serialization and deserialization, but I have the problem with installing this package. As I saw on the [website](http://json.codeplex.com/)  it supports wp 7.1 and silverilight. When I'm typing in console `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

```
Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'.
Adding 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1' to Connected.
Uninstalling 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project tha
t targets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references or conte
nt files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

How to solve this issue ?
How it should be properly done ?

Comment: +1 having the very same problems woth a windows phone 8.1 app - so it's nothing to do with windows 7

Answer (score 5):

With windows phone 7, you should probably install the older version of that package, such as 5.0.1. You can do Install-package Newtonsoft.Json -version 5.0.1

Comment: Json.Net was changed in [6.0 release 1](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/117958) to target Windows Phone 8 and Silverlight 5 instead of WP7 and SL4 for the .Net 4 portable build.  The last Json.Net version to target WP7 and SL4 was [5.0 release 8](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/113546)

Comment: I'm trying to add reference to Newtonsoft.Json.dll but for every file I get the error "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly connot be added to the project". I download firstly 5.0.8 and try with every file, then 5.0.1 the same here, and for 4.5.11 whats wrong with my way of adding this dll to my project. How should I do this to make it works for me?

Answer (score 0):

right click on dll,in general tab,security section

and unblock it

thanks to :
http://crodrigues.com/referencing-json-net-in-windows-phone-8/