# JSON.Net throws an exception on build

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm using `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync()` to download JSON string, and Json.Net's `JObject.Parse()` to parse that string into an JSON Object so I can query that object with LINQ. But when i try to build solution, it throws an exception and warning

```
Reference to type 'System.Func`2' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\mscorlib.dll', but it could not be found
```

using these packages:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Newtonsoft.Json; //v 6.0.3
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

Comment: Silverlight? Aren't you in a WP7 project?

Comment: You should try to build your project without this JSON treatment part, to check if it's not a problem from the start, because this error seems not to be linked.
Can you fully get the name of the reference throwing this error ? `System.Func2`

Comment: Have you tried to install silverlight? Have you imported right package?

Comment: Try cleaning references from you project, add them manually, then clean and rebuild your project

Comment: @NicolasR error is thrown by Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: @ZdeněkMlčoch silverlight is needed to install Visual Studio, which i have installed, so here isn't problem; and if it's wrong package, it would show me errors inline, i think

Comment: @lukIX_CZ: please also add the versions of the librairies you are using (especially Newtonsoft.Json), and how you get them (nuGet ?)

Comment: @NicolasR i downloaded only Newtonsoft.Json and via NuGet

Comment: Which version of Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: I'm using version 6.0.3

Comment: So the problem is here... this version seems not to be compatible, since 6.0: try 5.0.8 http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See other SO answer: [how to properly install Json.net via nuget for windows phone 7.1 and Silverlight v.4,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154618/how-to-properly-install-json-net-via-nuget-for-windows-phone-7-1-and-silverlight)

As you are targeting Windows Phone version before WP8, you should use older versions of Newtonsoft.Json.

You can do `Install-package Newtonsoft.Json -version 5.0.8` to get the version 5.0.8, but remove the 6.0.3 version before.